# Regular Expression Extractor JMeter query

Tags: regex, jmeter

Below is a situation where I use an API to generate a jwt token and that token is used in subsequent APIs in headers – Authorization.
Steps followed:

1. I am fetching the jwt token from **Thread 1 – Base Request**, in the response using Regular Expression Extractor within Thread 1 – Base Request.
2. Further, the extracted jwt token in above step is used to execute the Request **(Thread 1- Request 1)**.
3. Is there a way where the extracted jwt token in step 1, can be used in another thread, i.e., in **Thread 2 – Request 2** in Headers – Authorization for another request?

[image]

version-
Apache JMeter 5.4.1

Answer (score 1):

1. Regular Expression Extractor produces a [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. JMeter Variables are [local to the thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) (virtual user)

If you want to use the variable value in another thread (no matter this or another Thread Group) you need to:

- Either convert it into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in 1st Thread Group and read it using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in 2nd Thread Group
- Or use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter), this way you can "wait" until the token is available